# MySQL trouble with the strings.How to convert to utf8?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, utf-8, latin

I am having the following problem. I am creating a C# windows Forms application with which i want to transfer the data from a SQL Server to MySQL. The problem is that the data in the SQL is in latin and when i trasfer it in the MySQL DB it is shown like "?". Please give me some advice. I have tried to convet it but it does not work!

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your C# code that transfers the info?

Answer (score 0):

How are you selecting the data - using a sproc or sql command?

You can put a collate in the query (see : [MySql Manual Ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html)) and force the correct collation back to your app (if reading from MySql or MS SQL both support it). This is easier than trying to convert (which does not always work as character sets are different sizes) or changing the db charset/collation.